# Can't set idle and running animations properly in Andengine

Tags: animation, sprite, andengine

I´m trying to set an animation to my character when he is idle and another one when he moves right/left. Right now I have the following code in my game onUpdate:

```
if (!player_self_sprite.isAnimationRunning())
    if (isPlayerMoving)
        player_self_sprite.animate(new long[] { 100, 100, 100, 100}, 10 ,14, true);
    else
        player_self_sprite.animate(new long[] { 100, 100, 100, 100}, 14,18, true);
```

The problem is that the "idle" animation is not displayed until the "running" animation hasn't finished (even if my player has already stopped) The other way around is the same: my player can be moving but the animation is the idle one until it doesn't finish.

Isn't there a way in Andengine to make a differentece between two types of animations? If I use the "stopAnimation" code I may be stopping the wrong one.

Comment: Can you describe (or add the code) with "stopAnimation"? From the current code I can only admit that "isAnimationRunning" returns true until you manually call "player_self_sprite.stopAnimation()", so you can't check is player moving until that (manual animation stop).
P.S. my advice will be to stop existing and start the new animation in the place where you set "playerMoving" or somewhere not in onUpdate(). It's because onUpdate() called too many times per second. But it's only my opinnion.

Comment: I tried with that approach. The problem with that is I can set the new animation when the player starts moving (right and left) but I can't detect with user input when a player has stopped moving (that's why I moved it to the onUpdate method).

Comment: Can you paste the code, where you're reading the user input and start moving? I think it will help to give more accurate solution. Until that I will just describe the idea:  I think is that you have to track unit position changes. When unit position becomes permanent you can stop an animation (but it's a pity that you don't have possibility to detect "key release")

Comment: I can detect "key release" and set the idle animation when that happens. The problem is when I come from the "jumping" animation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it after 100 tests. The trick was to detect when the player was transitioning from "idle" to "moving" and viceversa in the onUpdate. When that happens (comparing the two booleans) I stop the animation that is taking place and I start the other one depending on the isPlayerMoving boolean. The summary code would be:

```
private boolean wasPlayerMoving = false;
private boolean isPlayerMoving = false;

...

Sprite left = new Sprite(-10, CAMERA_HEIGHT - 160, mLeftTextureRegion) {
    @Override
        public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pEvent, float pX, float pY) {

            if (!pEvent.isActionOutside() && !isDead && !isPaused) {
                isPlayerMoving = true;
            }

            if (pEvent.isActionUp())  {
                if (isPlayerMoving) {
                    isPlayerMoving = false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

  // similar code when pressing Right sprite
  ...

this.mScene.registerUpdateHandler(new IUpdateHandler() {
        public void onUpdate(float pSecondsElapsed) {

         // THE TRICK
         if (wasPlayerMoving!=isPlayerMoving)
                player_self_sprite.stopAnimation();

         if (!isNotJumping && !player_self_sprite.isAnimationRunning())
             if (isPlayerMoving)
                player_self_sprite.animate(...animation when moving..)
             else 
                player_self_sprite.animate(...animation when idle..)
        }

        wasPlayerMoving = isPlayerMoving;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Barbara. For complex state-dependent behaviours you can (f.e.) use the 'state machine' pattern (you'll find plenty of infos using Google). It will help you to build a better structure which is easier to debug.